# std::atomic and multicore processors

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

Consider that I have a `std::atomic<long>` variable, and two threads that both write to the variable.  I have a multicore machine so these two threads run truly concurrently.

Assuming that the writes happen at precisely the same time (if that is possible), what mechanism exists to ensure that the results of the two writes are not interleaved in any way?

Comment: Are you asking how `std::atomic` is implemented on your architecture, OS and compiler? We'd rather have to know what those things were...

Comment: The mechanism is using an `std::atomic<long>`, it makes sure that in this scenario one thread writes first and the other second. If you mean to ask how to implement that in assembler the answer is also pretty boring: there are instructions that do that.

Comment: Those mechanism depends on your implementation(i.e your OS and compiler and hardware)

Comment: Why do you care, anyway? Just code to standards, treat C++ as a black box, and you'll be fine. If you're _really_ asking "is `std::atomic` guaranteed to be atomic?" then the answer is, well, yes! That's its purpose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think this question is legit. Knowing the actual implementation is both interessting in regards to educational purposes, reverse engineering and performance considerations. Of course OP will have to be more concrete about his setup, otherwise answers will be too broad.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Well, good to know we have the answer already in our FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for commenting all, and sorry I didn't pick up the PAQ; I did search but evidently not well enough.  I have been reading about memory fences and how they synchronize the CPU caches but wasn't sure what would happen if writes occurred at precisely the same time.

Comment: @Wad In short: It never appears at the _exactly same time_, as this is prevented with appropriate hardware mechanisms.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann: You just contradicted yourself :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a 64-bit x86 processor, compiled with gcc, this code:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<long> x;

void foo()
{
  x += 1;
}
```

results in this assembler:

```
foo():
        lock addq       $1, x(%rip)
        ret
```

`lock` is an x86 instruction prefix which causes the processor (and memory caches) to ensure that the instruction is atomic and well ordered with respect to other cores' view of memory.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I'm not quite following that; what happens if the two processors both execute the `lock addq` line at the same time though, or isn't that possible?

Comment: Hmm, I found [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/discussion/71105/lock-instruction): _In a multiprocessor
: environment, the LOCK# signal insures that the processor has exclusive use of any shared: memory while the signal is asserted._ - does that sound correct to you?

Comment: @wad the processors have signal pathways between them (think of it like a hardware mutex) so one will stall while the other is updating this area of memory. So the two memory updates will happen sequentially. It's actually more complex than this, processors and cache circuitry is quite complicated and tries very hard not to stall if possible. However, that's a longer subject than we have room (or time) for here :)

Comment: @Wad yes, as a high level explanation that will do.